# Expression.Convert vs Expression.ConvertChecked

Tags: c#

What is the difference between `Expression.Convert` and `Expression.ConvertChecked`?

Any example, where the difference will be visible? (i.e. where the 2nd once would throw an Exception)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.convertchecked?view=netframework-4.7.2) `ConvertChecked` will throw when an overflow occurs, i.e. converting a number larger than `byte.MaxValue` (255) or smaller than `byte.MinValue` (0) to type `byte` – similarly all other numeric types.

Comment: Yes, numeric overflow makes a difference. So it applies to unboxed numeric types only/strictly?

Comment: You can only unbox to the exact type anyway (aside from lifting of nullables), e.g. `object boxed = 1; long unboxed = (long)boxed;` is an invalid operation. But yes checked only applies to type conversions to an numeric or rather to an integral type, see also the [documentation of the checked keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked-and-unchecked).